# How to derive a recursive formula from the following formula

Tags: numerical-methods, recursive-algorithms, fractional-calculus, fractional-iteration

How to derive a recursive formula from the following formula,

$$
u_{n}=a_{n-1}u_{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{n-1-k}-a_{n-k})u_{k}+\Gamma(2-\alpha)h^{\alpha}f(t_{n},u_{n})?
$$

P.S.:
Consider the following initial value problem (IVP) for $\ 0<\alpha<1$,
$$^{c}D_{0}^{\alpha}u(t)=f(t,u(t)),\\\ u(0)=u_{0},$$

where $^{c}D_{0}^{\alpha}$, denotes Caputo derivative and $f:\left[0,T\right]\times D\rightarrow R,\,D\subset R$.
Divide the interval $\left[0,T\right]$ into $N$ subintervals. Consider
an equispaced grid with step length $h=T/N$ with $t_{k}=kh,$ $k=0,1,...N$.

L1 method (The reference  [ [1](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0292.26011) ]) is used for the numerical evaluation of the fractional
derivatives of order $\alpha \ $, $0<\alpha<1$. The approximate $^{c}D_{0}^{\alpha}u(t)$
by the following formula:

$$
^{c}D_{0}^{\alpha}u(t)\mid_{t=t_{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_{n-k-1}\left(u_{k+1}-u_{k}\right)=f(t_{n},u_{n}),
$$
where $u_{k}$ denotes the approximate value of the solution of IVP
at $t=t_{k}$ and
$$
b_{n-k-1}=\frac{h^{-\alpha}}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)}\left((n-k)^{1-\alpha}-(n-k-1)^{1-\alpha}\right).
$$

The previous equation can be rewritten as:
$$
u_{n}=a_{n-1}u_{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(a_{n-1-k}-a_{n-k})u_{k}+\Gamma(2-\alpha)h^{\alpha}f(t_{n},u_{n}),
$$
where $a_{k}=(k+1)^{1-\alpha}-k^{1-\alpha}$. Note that: $f,u_{0},\alpha$
is known, $u(t_{k})\approx u_{k}$ and $h=T/N$ with $t_{k}=kh,k=0,1,...N$.

> My question: How to derive a recursive formula from the last formula?
> This is easier and useful for programming.